# Can a vector have more components than the dimension(D)

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I read in a book that a 2d vector has 2 components and a 3d vector has 3 components.I know that a 2d vector has 2 components but can it have 3 components or more and can a 3d vector have 4 or more components. If it is possible can someone help me with few examples and if not possible can someone give me a solid reason to believe.

Answer (score 1):

Such notions do not really make any sense. However, you can always project vectors unto subspaces, therefore you `lose one dimension'. For instance, if you have a horizontal plane in $\mathbf{R}^3$ and you project on that plane, your vectors will have one component that is constant.